# Cannot configure IntelliJ Idea to use @Immutables annotations

Tags: java, intellij-idea, immutables-library

I've followed the `Immutables` [tutorial](https://immutables.github.io/apt.html#intellij-idea) to use those annotations on `IntelliJ Idea`. For some reason the IDE is still showing the generated annotation classes as an error, though the `maven` compilation is going forward normally. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you try the classic `File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -> Invalidate and restart`?

Comment: Yes, I tried that with no luck =(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I finally ended up solving that by executing `Maven >> Generate Source and Update Folders`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using new Beta UI. I faced this problem today and fixed it by doing

> File > Invalidate Caches

I think they are aware of this [problem](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-303711)

Answer (score 0):

Adding the annotationPaths to maven compiler plugin worked for me.

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${project.build.targetJdk}</source>
                <target>${project.build.targetJdk}</target>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                <annotationProcessorPaths combine.children="append">
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.immutables</groupId>
                        <artifactId>value</artifactId>
                        <version>${immutables.version}</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Annotation Processors

Make sure this is enabled

Comment: This is exactly what is described in the official tutorial, not really helpful =(

Comment: Oh. I've run into similar problems like this with Lombok as well where nothing helped apart from changing the dependency version in my maven build even though I was using the exact same configuration as the tutorial I followed to set it up. Try editing your pom.xml file to use a different version.